# how to mute a looping html5 video following initial playthrough

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am currently attempting to create a webpage with video that loops for 30 seconds. The video plays audio, but I only want the audio to play on the initial loop. Afterwards, I want it to loop muted.

Here is my current unsuccessful attempt, the event listener does not seem to activate due to the loop:

```
<video id="introvid" autoplay loop onended="muteVid()">
    <source src="assets/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
function muteVid()
        {
            var video = document.getElementById("introvid");
            video.muted= true;
        }
</script>
```

Is there another way to mute the video on all subsequent loops?
Thanks

Comment: Replace your function with mine and let me know if it works

Comment: Sadly, that does not seem to work. Could it possibly be related to the 'onended' listener?